# Add double.MaxValue + double.MaxValue

Tags: c#, double

I have been asked this question in an interview, and I was told by the interviewer there is valid way to get the output. Need to add two `double` values:

```
double d = double.MaxValue;
double d1 = double.MaxValue;

var c = d + d1;
```

But I get `double.PositiveInfinity` as a result. I need to store a large number in the output.

Comment: If you need to add *decimal* values, you quite possibly shouldn't be using *double* to start with. What are these values actually meant to represent, and do you *really* need values greater than 10^308?

Comment: There's a reason `double.MaxValue` is called `double.MaxValue`: there are no (finite) values greater than `double.MaxValue` (at least not in that type). What result were you expecting?

Comment: Um, `MaxValue` is the *maximum value* that the type can hold. What are you expecting?

Comment: Take a walk man, towards Tube station!

Comment: I have been asked this question in an interview and I was told by the inteviewer there is valid way to get the output.

Comment: @user3293264 If inteviewer said that exactly, you can be sure you're lucky not to be hired `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the interviewer meant for you to use a [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using System.Numerics;

double d = double.MaxValue;
double d1 = double.MaxValue;

var c = new BigInteger(d) + new BigInteger(d1);
Console.WriteLine(c); // 359538626972463...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is best solution I have got till but if I use BigInteger I will loose the precision values.

Comment: Won't that cause an OutOfMemoryException that can be thrown for any operation that causes a BigInteger value to grow too large, BigInterger is still a value type, a value type shouldn't be bigger than 16 bytes

Comment: @user3293264 When a `double` value is large enough (and `double.MaxValue` is definitely large enough), it won't have enough precision to represent any data after the decimal point. You won't lose any data.

Comment: @AymenDaoudi `BigInteger` is a value type that itself contains reference types, to store data elsewhere if it gets too large. You should have no problems unless your numbers get so large that the representation doesn't fit into memory, but that only happens when your numbers have billions of digits, not hundreds as is the case here.

Comment: I will mark as Answered, as I also feel it is not possible to add 2 max.double values other than losing precision.

Comment: @user3293264 Actually, I wasn't sure if what *hvd* said was true until I did the math myself. `double.MaxValue` is `(1 + (1 − 2^−52)) * 2^1023` or `2^1024 - 2^971` which is clearly an integer, so converting it to a `BigInteger` does not loose any precision.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that many interview questions aren't meant for you to find a *solution*, but rather to see how you go about solving the problem.

So the right answer would be - how would *you* solve it?  If you chose to use `Biginteger` you may get dinged for losing the floating-point precision.

Another possibility would be to create a "BigFloat" class that internally stores data in an arbitrary number of `double`s, and does the math on those doubles to generate (theoretically) infinitely large floating-point numbers.  (same principle as `BigInteger` but with different arithmetic).

Again, the focus may not be on the *answer* so much as how you *think*.

Comment: "but rather to see how you go about solving the problem." - ask Stack Overflow (which BTW is not a bad answer)

Comment: That's a horrible answer for an interview :)

Comment: Those exact words maybe but "Ask someone who knows" is definitely a good answer. It goes along the line of "How to you find the weight of a Boeing 747"/"Look up Boeing's phone number and call their engineering department"

Comment: Again - it goes to "how would _you_ solve the problem". Another answer might be to estimate the volume and density of the 747... OK not a good example, but showing original thought is definitely preferred in an interview.  _Anyone_ can ask SO for an answer (or call Boeing :) ).

Answer (score -2):

Declare d and d1 as double and c as decimal, i think it will be work !

Look at that : http://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programmation_C_sharp/Les_types_de_base_et_les_d%C3%A9clarations

Comment: How do you know OP knows French? `:)`

Comment: The most important is the table on this page

Comment: Decimal is smaller than double for your knowledge